# What happened to Dark Helmet, Colonel Sandurz and President Skroob?

Tags: spaceballs

After they landed on the Planet of the Apes, what happened to Dark Helmet, Colonel Sandurz and President Skroob?

Were they captured and forced into ape slavery? Was there ever a description of their ultimate fate?

Comment: They definitely didn't get any helmet...

Comment: Presumably answered in the periodically promised sequel.

Comment: The apes definitely assumed that the Spaceballs would take over the planet, so I think the apes were the ones who were going to get screwed.

Comment: To quote Sgt Schultz: *I know nothing.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an [interview](http://youbentmywookie.com/features/ybmw-interview-spaceballs-george-wyner-17153) with George Wyner (the actor who portrayed Colonel Sandurz), there was in fact some additional ending material that was filmed but never made it into the final cut:

> Q. *...What do you think happened to Colonel Sandurz when he found
>   himself on a planet of apes?*
>
> **George Wyner:** *We actually filmed an ending that was never used. After the escape pod lands, and President Scroob, Dark Helmet, and
>   Colonel Sandurz climb safely out, the three of them march down the
>   beach together. President Scroob asks, “Where are we?” Colonel Sandurz
>   answers, “California,” and President Scroob barks out, “Let’s pollute
>   it!”*.
>
> ***Scroob, along with his trusted aides Dark Helmet and Colonel Sandurz,
>   made a fortune polluting California, and is now considering running
>   for president.***

Answer (score 5):

They went on to further adventures in [Spaceballs: the Animated Series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceballs:_The_Animated_Series).

Including opening casinos, playing video games and cloning dinosaurs.

[image]

Comment: What canon level is the spaceballs tv series?

Comment: It's written, produced and voiced by Mel Brooks. So I'd say it's Plaid-level canon, maybe even ludicrous-level canon.

Comment: I think that's worthy of its own question.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have enough information to come to any conclusions, but the apes themselves clearly assume that the Spaceballs will have the upper hand:

> 1ST APE
>   Dear me, what are those things coming out of her nose?
>
> The 2ND APE looks through binoculars. He sees COL SANDURZ on the ground, DARK HELMET is climbing down a rope, followed by SKROOB. SKROOB steps on DARK HELMET'S helmet.
>
> DARK HELMET
>   (mask up) Hey, hey, watch my helmet.
>
> The 2ND APE stops looking in the binoculars.
>
> 2ND APE
>   Spaceballs?
>
> 1ST APE
>   **Oh shit, there goes the planet.**

Being experienced bureaucrats, it seems likely that the Spaceballs will soon be destroying their new planet.